# How to auto generate objects name in java by using available data?

Tags: java, oop

```
package sms;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class Student {
    PrintStream p=new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String reg;
    Student(){
        //p.println("Enter the name of the student:");
    }
    public void nstd() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<String> cse=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ece=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mec=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> eee=new ArrayList<String>();
        p.println("Enter the name of the student:");
        String name=br.readLine();
        p.println("Choose one group from fallowing:");
        String group=br.readLine();
        if(group=="cse"||group=="CSE"){
            cse.add(name);
            Acad name=new Acad();
        }
        if(group=="ece"||group=="ECE"){
            ece.add(name);
        }
        if(group=="MEC"||group=="mec"){
            mec.add(name);
        }
        if(group=="eee"||group=="EEE"){
            eee.add(name);
            }
    }
}
```

in the above code after adding an element to cse arraylist with the name provided i tried to create an object with the name but it shows duplicate variables found.
how can i create an object with unique name for every student entry that can be with name or arraylist name fallowed by elements index (like cse0,cse1,etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variable names dynamically in Java. Variable name is a compile time thing. However you can dynamically refer to the declared variables at runtime through reflection.

But here in your case you should use `array` of objects(`Acad`) or `List` or `Map` of these objects to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't declare variable names dynamically. Java variable names are declared compile time not Run-time.

But from what I can understand from your question you can achieve this using a `Map`. Using a `Map` you can store an Object with a key of your definition.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Student {
    PrintStream p=new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String reg;
    Student(){
        //p.println("Enter the name of the student:");
    }

    public void nstd() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<String> cse=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ece=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mec=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> eee=new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Acad> cseStudents= new HashMap<>();
        p.println("Enter the name of the student:");
        String name=br.readLine();
        p.println("Choose one group from fallowing:");
        String group=br.readLine();
        if(group.matches("^[Cc][Ss][Ee]$")){
            cse.add(name);
            cseStudents.put(name,new Acad());
        }
        if(group.matches("^[Ee][Cc][Ee]$")){
            ece.add(name);
        }
        if(group.matches("^[Mm][Ee][Cc]$")){
            mec.add(name);
        }
        if(group.matches("^[Ee]{3}$")){
            eee.add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

You can access the required object anytime using

```
Acad required=cseStudents.get(name);
```

There are few types of `Map` implementations that could be useful to you [HashMap][1], LinkedHashMap, TreeMap and Hashtable.

Each have there own advantages. Basically,

1. **HashMap**

   > This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
   >   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
   >   over time. This implementation provides constant-time performance for
   >   the basic operations (get and put).
2. **LinkedHashMap**

   > This linked list maintains the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).
3. **TreeMap**

   > The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
4. **Hashtable**
   Almost similar to HashMap except for this is synchronized.